# Terraform: How to use security group id in tfvars

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating an RDS option group with several options and one of them has the parameter "vpc_security_group_memberships" which takes the ID of a security group.
db_options.tfvars:

```
db_options = [
{
    option_name = "OEM_AGENT"
    option_settings = [
      {
        name  = "AGENT_REGISTRATION_PASSWORD"
        value = "****"
      },
      {
        name  = "OMS_HOST"
        value = "gridcontrol.example.com"
      },
      {
        name  = "OMS_PORT"
        value = "4000"
      }
    ]
    port                           = "3872"
    version                        = "13.5.0.0.v1"
    vpc_security_group_memberships = [ ]
  }
]
```

And I create a security group in sg.tf:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "db-sg" {
  description = "Allow access to RDS instance"
  name = "${var.env}.${var.db_name}.sg"

  tags = {
    Name            = "${var.env}.${var.db_name}.sg"
  }

  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}
```

Is it possible to put the aws_security_group.db-sg.id for use in vpc_security_group_memberships?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to put the aws_security_group.db-sg.id for use in vpc_security_group_memberships?

Sadly its **not possible**. TF variables can't be dynamic. They must be fully defined at plan time. But you can instead use [locals](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals). Local values can by dynamic.

Comment: Yes, I also tried with locals, but doesn't seem to work or maybe I am doing it wrong: `locals { sg_id = aws_security_group.db-sg.id }`
And then in tfvars:
`vpc_security_group_memberships = [ local.sg_id ]`
But again it complains about "variables not allowed"

Comment: @XerX Locals work. Only local variables can be dynamic, not regular vars. My answer is correct and correctly addresses your problem.

Comment: Well i still receive the error. I ended up putting the oem_agent option in my main.tf, since all my dbs will have it anyway.

Comment: @XerX Yo haven't provided the code of what you did in locals, so its not possible to say why you get the error. You can make new question about it, if you are not sure how to use locals.